# What's the point of multi-producer multi-consumer channels when the receiving channel needs to be wrapped in a Mutex to be read from multiple therads?

Tags: rust, concurrency

I'm looking at Flume's unbounded channel (mpmc), but i'm confused why it's named as it is, because the consumer channel needs to be wrapped in a mutex in order to receive messages from it from multiple threads? What would the difference between an mpmc and mpsc be then?

Answer (score 3):

Someone on the Rust Community Discord gave me an answer:

I was told that `flume::Receiver` implements `Clone + Send + Sync` so it needn't be wrapped in a Mutex. And I simply just need to clone a reference the receiver and send it off to threads.

Comment: You should notice what you do need. What I mean is that messages are not being broadcasted to all receivers, just one of them  will receive one at a time.